What does this "Wouldn't you know?" mean in this context? If's from the "Fatal Attraction" movie
What does this "Wouldn't you know?" mean in this context?
If's from the "Fatal Attraction" movie. The script is here
MAN: Wait, let me just...
Let me just look at you.
You're so beautiful.
Just so beautiful. [DOORBELL RINGS]
WOMAN: Wouldn't you know?
I know.
Here is the screen-capture of the scenes.
Is this  "Wouldn't you know?" an idiomatic expression as defined in Merriam-Websters
as follows:

wouldn't you know it? idiom informal —used to say that something
annoying that has happened is the kind of thing that often happens.
I was running late and—wouldn't you know?—I rushed off without my purse.
"He's late again." "Wouldn't you know it?!"

So, does that mean their expression of affection is interrupted by the doorbell which signals their friends arrival, and they are feeling a little bit of displeasure?
Or does it mean something else?
Thank you.

She says: Wouldn't you know? [the damn doorbell would ring at the wrong moment]. Then, she answers him: I know [I am beautiful] You have to post things so they make sense. That's all. Yes, it means what the MW says. That is not a screen capture; it is the actual scene.

Thank you for the comment, Lambie.  But does "I know" mean "I know I am beautiful"?  I thought it means "I know our friends have arrived from the doorbell sound". Am I wrong?  Thank you.

Yes, I think you are. Waiting for friends is not even on the horizon.

But, Dan, the guy said "I know",  Then does it mean "Dan knows he is beautiful?"

wouldn't you know can be used to indicate something like "and fate rubbed salt in the wound".  Not only did something bad happen, but things got worse, as they do when luck has taken a turn  from good to bad.

They changed my schedule and I had to work the weekend, so I lined up a babysitter, but wouldn't you know, the babysitter got sick, so I had to tell them I couldn't come in to work, and they docked my pay.

That doesn't mean that the babysitter often gets sick. It means that on top of having to work the weekend and pay for a babysitter (which is a hardship for someone working a low-paying hourly job with an erratic schedule),  the employee had to say they couldn't work the weekend, and so the company paid them nothing for those days. The week turned out to be one in which their earnings, already low, became even lower.
P.S. In many circumstances, the phrase "wouldn't you know" is spoken with a good deal of emotion. It is a kind of exclamation. In the movie scene, the words of the phrase are delivered with an atypical detachment and calm.
P.P.S. I should add that the phrase can have the opposite meaning, something like "and in yet another stroke of good fortune":

I was running a little late for work but the train was delayed five minutes so I didn't miss it, and when I got to my building in the city, wouldn't you know, the normally crowded elevator was completely empty, so I didn't have to stop ten times and wait for people to get out before reaching my floor!

So, if you had to boil its meaning down to the point where the emotional content is removed, it would be "and, as you can guess, in yet more of the same".

Thank you TimR for the detailed explanation.  I am the OP, and I was wondering why "Wouldn't you know" took on that particularly negative connotation when the sentence itself does not have anything to imply that.  And you answered my question in your P.P.S. Thank you.
